# Can't Compile Xamarin UWP App

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, compiler-errors, uwp

I created this repo:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Adapt.Presentation.git

I haven't been able to get any of the samples in this project compiling or running. I'm biting one off at a time. In particular the UWP sample won't compile or run. For a start, the code that Visual Studio is generating has compilation errors. I have tried Git cleaning the solution over and over. I have also deleted all the Xamarin temp files here: C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local

I have the latest version of Xamarin , and Visual Studio 2017 (15.2 26430.12).

Xamarin   4.5.0.476 (1be4f0c)

Xamarin.Android SDK   7.3.1.2 (9dbc4c5)

Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   10.10.0.35 (4cffddf)

How can I get it to compile and run?

These are the errors I get :

[image]

Obviously, all the compilation errors are in the generated code that I have no control over.

Comment: Have you installed Windows 10 SDK ( version 10.0.10240.0). You could check it by using "visual studio installer ".

Comment: Good question! It turns out that I didn't. So, I set the target and minimum versions to 10586 which I definitely do have installed. That has solved some of my errors, but I still get all the other errors. I've checked the change in to source control at the repo specified.

Comment: I have checked the other errors. they seems to appear in your custom library.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that at all?

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that there was no default root namespace in the highest level project. It turns out that if you do not specify a default root namespace in a UWP project, it generates code incorrectly. This makes sense.I consider it a bug in Visual Studio or the csproj format, but at least I know why it is happening now.